# How to export a selection of properties/columns and retain the configuration defined via attributes using CsvHelper?

Tags: c#, .net, csvhelper

Consider the following class that has configuration specified using attributes:

```
    public class SomeClass
    {
        public int SomeInteger { get; set; }
        public string SomeString { get; set; }
        public float SomeFloat { get; set; }
    
        [BooleanFalseValues("No")]
        [BooleanTrueValues("Yes")]
        public bool SomeBoolean { get; set; }
    
        [Format(@"#\%")]
        public decimal SomeDecimal { get; set; }
    
        [Format("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")]
        public DateTime SomeDateTime { get; set; }
    }
```

And this function that will accept a list of data objects and a list of fields to export to CSV. If `fields` is `null`, all properties will be exported.

```
    public static byte[] GetAsCsvByteArray<T>(IEnumerable<T> data, string[] fields)
    {
        var csvConfig = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        {
            Delimiter = ";",
            ShouldQuote = _ => true
        };

        using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        using var writer = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);
        using var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, csvConfig);

        if (fields?.Length > 0)
        {
            var csvMap = new DefaultClassMap<T>();

            foreach (var field in fields)
            {
                var property = typeof(T).GetProperty(field);
                csvMap.Map(typeof(T), property);
            }

            csv.Context.RegisterClassMap(csvMap);
        }

        csv.WriteRecords(data);

        return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
```

When calling this method with `fields` as `null`, the export is correctly formatted.
When calling this method with `fields` containing an array of property names (e.g. `["SomeInteger", "SomeBoolean"]`), the configuration is lost and the export is not correctly formatted.

Any idea how to retain the attribute configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can get the custom attributes from the class and add them to the mapping.

```cs
foreach (var field in fields)
{
    var property = typeof(T).GetProperty(field);

    csvMap.Map(typeof(T), property);
    
    var attributes = property.GetCustomAttributes();

    foreach (var attribute in attributes)
    {
        var attributeType = attribute.GetType();

        if (attributeType == typeof(BooleanFalseValuesAttribute))
            csvMap.Map(typeof(T), property).Data.TypeConverterOptions.BooleanFalseValues.AddRange(((BooleanFalseValuesAttribute)attribute).FalseValues);

        if (attributeType == typeof(BooleanTrueValuesAttribute))
            csvMap.Map(typeof(T), property).Data.TypeConverterOptions.BooleanTrueValues.AddRange(((BooleanTrueValuesAttribute)attribute).TrueValues);

        if (attributeType == typeof(ConstantAttribute))
            csvMap.Map(typeof(T), property).Data.Constant = ((ConstantAttribute)attribute).Constant;

        if (attributeType == typeof(FormatAttribute))
            csvMap.Map(typeof(T), property).Data.TypeConverterOptions.Formats = ((FormatAttribute)attribute).Formats;

        if (attributeType == typeof(IgnoreAttribute))
            csvMap.Map(typeof(T), property).Data.Ignore = true;

        if (attributeType == typeof(IndexAttribute))
            csvMap.Map(typeof(T), property).Data.Index = ((IndexAttribute)attribute).Index;

        if (attributeType == typeof(NameAttribute))
            csvMap.Map(typeof(T), property).Data.Names.AddRange(((NameAttribute)attribute).Names);

        if (attributeType == typeof(OptionalAttribute))
            csvMap.Map(typeof(T), property).Data.IsOptional = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works! I've corrected the line setting the `Formats` property in your code snippet.

Comment: For later reference I've added the "missing" attributes to your code snippet too.